# Can i change the order of quantifiers in this case?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In this sentence:

"No hero is cowardly and some soldiers are cowards."

Assuming 
h(x) = x is a hero

s(x) = x is a soldier

c(x) = x is a coward.

So the sentence is like this i think:

($\forall x\ (h(x) \longrightarrow \neg C(x)) \land (\exists y\ (s(y) \land  C(y))$

In this case, are prenex formulas bellow the same thing?

$\forall x\ \exists y\  (\neg h(x) \lor \neg C(x)) \land ((s(y) \land  C(y))$

$\exists y\ \forall x\  (\neg h(x) \lor \neg C(x)) \land ((s(y) \land  C(y))$

Comment: The last line is obviously wrong. The second last one I think is correct.

Comment: @Lyunth: I wonder if your qeustion is about the following formulas:
\begin{align*}
&\forall x\ \exists y\  (\neg h(x) \lor \neg C(x)) \land ((s(y) \land \neg C(y)), \\
&\exists y\ \forall x\  (\neg h(x) \lor \neg C(x)) \land ((s(y) \land \neg C(y))
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, you're right. sorry for my mistake

Comment: Either the original statement was "... some soldiers are **not** cowards" or your formulas have an unwanted $\neg$ before the second $C$.

Comment: Thank you, i've edited too. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Quite generally, for any formulas $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(y)$ with only the indicated free variables, the formula
$$
(\forall x\,\alpha(x))\land(\exists y\,\beta(y))
$$
is equivalent to both of
$$
\forall x\exists y\,(\alpha(x)\land\beta(y))
$$
and 
$$
\exists y\forall x\,(\alpha(x)\land\beta(y)).
$$

Comment: thanks for response. is that works for $(\forall x\,\alpha(x))\lor (\exists y\,\beta(y))$ too?

Comment: Yes, it also works for "or".

Comment: ok, and what about the case which (∀x∀yα(x,y))∨(∃zβ(z)) are these interchangable too? (E.g: (∀x∀y)(∃z)(α(x,y)∨(∃zβ(z)) == (∃z)(∀x∀y)(α(x,y)∨(∃zβ(z))

Comment: The quantifiers are fine but you seem to be missing a parenthesis at the end of your formulas.  In general, the $x$ and the $y$ in my answer and my comment about $\lor$ can be lists of variables rather than single variables, but the lists should be disjoint.

Comment: so (∀x∀y)(∃z)(α(x,y)∨(∃zβ(z)) == (∃z)(∀x∀y)(α(x,y)∨(∃zβ(z)) == ∀x∃z∀y(α(x,y)∨(∃zβ(z))?

Comment: and what you mean with "the lists should be disjoint"? thanks for the feedback.

Comment: These formulas look weird, because we normally don't quantify a variable (in this case $z$) twice with one quantifier being in the scope of the other.  And these formulas are not an instance of what I wrote before.  But technically yet, they are equivalent (because the earlier of the two $z$ quantifiers has no effect, quantifying a formula in which $z$ isn't free).  And you're still missing parentheses.

Comment: Disjoint means that no variable should occur in both lists.

Comment: Understood. Thank you @Andreas Blass

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the other responses here,

$\forall x\ (h(x) \longrightarrow \neg C(x)) \land (\exists y\ (s(y) \land \neg C(y))$ is equivalent to $\forall x\ \exists y\  (\neg h(x) \lor \neg C(x)) \land ((s(y) \land \neg C(y))$, but not equivalent to $\exists x\ \forall y\  (\neg h(x) \lor \neg C(x)) \land ((s(y) \land \neg C(y))$

Comment: I've just edited the post above, I wrote the formulas wrong. i appreciate if you could help me.